# Does GNU time memory output account for child processes too?

Tags: linux, time, gnu

When running GNU time (`/usr/bin/time`) and checking for memory consumption, does its output account for the memory usage of the child processes of my target program?

Could not find anything in GNU's time manpage.

Comment: Can you post example output of the time utility? Can you exactly pinpoint about which measured value you ask? About `%K`? I can see gnu time interanlly uses [wait3](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait3) and just parses returned rusage (it also calls some `times` and `gettimeofday` but irrelevand for memory measuring). `wait3` says "return resource usage information about the child" - I think this implies resource information about one and one child only.

Comment: 1) `export TIME="\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys,\t%K amem,\t%M mmem"`
2) run the following `/usr/bin/time my_program.sh`. Output from `/usr/bin/time`:
`0:00.74 real, 1.16 user, 0.14 sys, 0 amem, 68636 mmem`

Comment: @KamilCuk  you're mistaken. you should always take linux documentation with a grain of salt ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

You can easily check with:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f '%M' sh -c 'perl -e "\$y=q{x}x(2*1024*1024)" & wait'
8132
$ /usr/bin/time -f '%M' sh -c 'perl -e "\$y=q{x}x(8*1024*1024)" & wait'
20648
```

GNU time is using the [`wait4`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) system call on Linux (via the `wait3` glibc wrapper), and while undocumented, the resource usage it returns in the `struct rusage` also includes the descendands of the process waited for. You can look at the kernel implementation of `wait4` in [`kernel/exit.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/exit.c) for all the details:

```
$ grep -C2 RUSAGE_BOTH include/uapi/linux/resource.h
#define RUSAGE_SELF     0
#define RUSAGE_CHILDREN (-1)
#define RUSAGE_BOTH     (-2)            /* sys_wait4() uses this */
#define RUSAGE_THREAD   1               /* only the calling thread */
```

FreeBSD and NetBSD also have a [`wait6`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wait3&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&format=html) system call which returns separate info for the process waited for and for its descendants. They also clearly document that the rusage returned by `wait3` and `wait4` also includes grandchildren.